# How to async socket in c++ (vs2010)?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, tcp

I would like to ask about c++ asynchronous tcp/ip.

I'm making a DLL, and this DLL needs tcp/ip asynchronous communication. I didn't know how to do it, so I looked into winsock 2.h, and it was mainly used by MFC. However, since I'm a DLL, I can't use functions such as WSAAsyncSelect like MFC. I'm not sure.

What should I do?

Comment: Depends on how you want to design your library. Would you want to provide it with its own thread? Would you want to let the user do the asynchronous work and just provide the `HANDLE` and a callback? Maybe even provide both and let the user select which one appears more appropriate to him...

Comment: I want just asynchronous socket work..  I don't know how. haha.

Comment: This now sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – what do you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: Actually, i want to make async Client in tcp/ip. Non-blocking ? Now i success make a socket, connect the server, send the data. But, the program is stopped until it is received. i wanna solve it.

Comment: Maybe, the code i make it is bad.

Comment: Try https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: I tried do this and fail....  Thank you comment.

Comment: What you are looking for is a tutorial.  This really isn't the place for that.

Comment: Actually you should provide your code – in form of a [mre], so ommitting whatever is not relevant for the problem.

Comment: Anyway you should think a bit about how you would want to design the library, how some user code and the library should interact with one another. You could provide your library with an equivalent to the main function of an ordinary executable that waits for the socket and optionally other handles a user might add together with a callback. Such a thing could be implemented via [`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsawaitformultipleevents). You could run a separate thread or you could leave waiting for input to the user.